# Get CSRF token from page & POST it

Tags: php

I need to create a script to login into a website. Saying that, so I'm going to grab **CSRF** token from the login page and POST it to the login action URL. [Accepted data is json.]

This is login method:

```
public function login()
{
    $login = 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $csrf = $this->token();
    $data = array(
        "email" => 'email@email.com',
        "password"  => '123456',
        "displayType"   => 'json',
        "csrf"  => $csrf
    );
    $json = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init($login);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // For debugging purposes
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

And here is token grabber method:

```
public function token()
{
    $source = $this->get("https://OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($source);
    $dxp = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $csrf = $dxp->query('//input[@name="csrf"]/@value')->item(0)->value;
    return $csrf;
}
```

Token is successfully extracted, but is changed on every call within the same session. **Why**?! I'm initializing session this way:

```
public function __construct($url)
{
    if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
        session_start();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don’t see you passing any session id to the remote site … or is that supposed to be contained within the URL in `$login` or the headers you are passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course $this->get( and your function login use different "session" on the called website.
you need to store cookies with the sessions and re-use the same. You need to rewrite your get function with cURL and add these lines:

```
$cookie_path = 'mycookie.txt';
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookie_path );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_path );
```